# Is it possible to insert multiple excel sheets from the same workbook in a word document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I am preparing a document in Word which needs to include several worksheets from one Excel File.  When I insert the object from create file it inserts the most recently opened worksheet.  The problem arises when I attempt to update any links because they default back to the most recently opened sheet.

I saw [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/943925/how-to-import-several-worksheets-from-a-single-excel-file-to-microsoft-word-docu) similar to this which was answered, but the field code provided was incorrect.  Can someone please help?  I really just need to know where to input the sheet and cell range reference.

The code I'm using is

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.8 "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\SFA Project Statistics 10-31-16.xls" "" \a \f 0 \p }
```

The sheet I'm using is `Sheet8!A1I67`

Comment: Can you provide the link to the similar question, and more importantly, what have you tried (with screenshot, if possible) and what doesn't work?

Comment: `But the field code provided was incorrect` what was in your code that does not work? Can you show us your code?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but try changing the `8` to `1`

Comment: @Vylix - Do you think you can revisit my question with the updated sheet information?

Comment: Try adding your sheet `Sheet8!A1I67` to the second block of double quote (before `\a`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can embed data from different workbooks and different worksheets in the same manner. Start off with your word document opened:

[image]

Open your excel sheet you wish to embed. I put some test data for my example. Select the region you wish to embed and press CTRL + C or right click and select copy:
[image]

Now select your word document and either press CTRL + V. The paste dialog comes up. Select to keep the link.

[image]

Now if the word document is closed and the excel section you copied, ever changes you will see this dialog when you open it up again:

[image]

Simply click Yes.

This same exact method works if you copy from multiple regions, from different workbooks, different worksheets, or the same.

This is done without VBA but Excel keeps the links stored behind the scenes.

Comment: Even though I get the notification shown, I've found that I have to right-click each table in the Word document, then click "update link" to get actual updates.

Comment: Oops.  It looks like my problem was an interaction with OneDrive.  As long as I have both Word and Excel files on local disk, it works like a champ!  Thanks!